# how to limit repeated value of a colunm in inserting values from another tables

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert value into one column from select from another table and limit 
 repeating this value.

I tried:

```
 update Student  set  Sup_Name =(select  top 1  Supervisors.Sup_Name from  Supervisors
 order by NewId())where  student.St_ID = '98754'
```

Comment: Why you use "update" to "insert" new row?

Comment: because I want to insert into one column not for all column